# AJAX : undefined index after serialize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with AJAX. I want to send a value I get with a form, and then do something with this value on my PHP script.

But I have always "undefined index" and I don't understand why.

My form :

```
<form target="../app/DisplayController.php" method="post" class="form-group month-chose col-6 mx-auto" id="form-month"> 
        <select class="form-control" id="month" name="month">
            <option value=''>Chose :</option>
            <?php foreach($viewVars[2] as $result): ?>
                <option value='<?=$result->getId();?>'><?=$result->getMonth();?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-3">Ok</button>
</form>
```

Here you have my JS code :

```
$('.month-chose').on('submit', function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var answers = $('#form-month').serialize();
            console.log(answers);
            $.ajax({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '../app/inc/chose-month.php',
                data: answers,
                success: $('.month-chose').load('../app/inc/chose-month.php')
            });
        })
```

My data are OK, my consol.log return "month=2".

And here my PHP test script (chose-month.php) :

```
<?php
echo 'Hi I'm ' . $_POST['month']; ?>
```

When I load the template, I have this famous "month: undefined index".

Thx for ur help !

Comment: Yeah, you would since you're doing an AJAX request with the POST data, then when that returns success, you're doing another request without any data.

Comment: Hmm I have to send data when I load my page chose-month ?

Comment: when you load file chose-month.php you need to give any param i guess like on the first call you pass $('#form-month').serialize(); using var answers. the second call of the same php file is returning nothing because i suppose it needs any param to process and return you some results.

Comment: Thank you guys, my problem is solved, indeed u saw right !